# Python Scapy use multiple CPU

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scapy, python-multiprocessing

Im struggling with the fact that my functions in python, for generating packets for Scapy, are only using 1 CPU at a time. I have searched for multipleprocessing, but i really dont know how i could implement it. I also tried to use some ThreadPool, but the result is the same.

Here is a snip of my code.

```
def code(a,b,c)

    while a < b :
        ## build pkt 100000 times

  send(pkt)

def main():
    ##defining some intregers a b c
    code(a,b,c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

When doing this, the while function is only being computed by 1 CPU. This takes too long time, to generate thousands of packets.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your packet list in chunks and let processes do the job for you.

EDIT: Python3 or the concurrent module is required.
The previous examples were just giving an idea. This one is the working solution. Feel free to change the constant values.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


START = 0
END = 1000000
CHUNK_SIZE = 1000


chunks = range(START, END, CHUNK_SIZE)


def code(offset):
    packets = []
    chunk = offset + CHUNK_SIZE

    for index in range(offset, chunk):
        packet = build_packet(index)
        packets.append(packet)

    return packets


with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    packets = []

    for chunk in executor.map(code, chunks):
        packets += chunk

send(packets)
```

Comment: i  really dont know what you mean :D im trying to implement it, but dont see what these commands do. Can you please explain it more?

Comment: if I understood correctly you question, what you want to do is to send multiple packets concurrently right? In such case what the logic is doing is splitting the packets in chunks and dispatching each chunk to a worker of the thread pool. Is your packet creation logic CPU intensive?

Comment: I am creating like thousands of packets in 1 time. All of them, i put in some matrix. Then this matrix is being sent out. There is a loop that creates these packets, and i see that 1 CPU (of 8 in total) is doing all the job.

Comment: Ok so in such case it's a CPU bound job rather than IO. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Its getting a bit clearer. Is the "chunks=range.." the same as chunk? Also what is the range? What to fill in for the a and b? Example chunksize is 1000, if cpu is 8, do i divide 1000 in 8 pieces to fill in the a-b ranges? Also i got the problem with "no module named concurrent.futures". Im running python 2.7.6 and scapy 2.3.1.

Comment: The no module error i got solved. The futures module was missing.

Comment: I assumed you were using Python3, if not you need to install the backport. range(0, 10, 2) -> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]. The range simply divides the total amount in chunks, the size should be big enough to justify the use of a separate process to compute it. The Pool will automatically spawn as many workers as CPU you have, and handle the workload for you.

Comment: I have added some config to my script. Dont we need to define/set "chunk" and "offset"? Also can you explain what is happening in here: for index in range(offset, chunk):         packet = build_packet(index)         packets.append(packet)

Comment: Because now my script looks like making the first 1000 packets and then i got the following error: file ".../queues.py" line 265, in _feed      Send(obj)          PicklingError: cant pickle <type 'function'>:............

Comment: That simply replaces your `while a < b` using a range generator. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95135/discussion-between-noxdafox-and-serdar-ebeng).